# URL Rewrite-rule in IIS 8 not triggering

Tags: iis, web-config, iis-8

I have a problem with my URL rewrite and I don't know what I'm doing wrong so, maybe you can point me in the right direction. We had a intranet-site, which had a pattern like this: `intranet.old-site.com`. Now we got a new domain and I want to forward my outdated links to the front-page of our new intranet, which looks like: `intranet.new-site.com`.

I installed the URL Rewrite module in IIS and in my point of view, the setup is correct:

**Match URL**

```
Request URL: matches pattern.
Using:       Wildcards
Pattern:     *intranet.old-site*
Ignore case: true
```

**Conditions**

```
none
```

**Server Variables**

```
none
```

**Action**

```
Action Type:                         Rewrite
Action Properties:                   Rewrite-URL: http://intranet.new-site.com/
Append query string:                 true
Log rewritten URL:                   false
Stop processing of subsequent rules: false
```

I'm also open for any idea what might work, so if there is a rule for the `web.config`, I could try that as well.

**Update 1:**

the web-config looks like this now:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="RewriteSG2DE" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*).sgbdd.saint-gobain(.*)" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="intranet.stark-deutschland.net" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="(.*)sgbdd.saint-gobain(.*)" />
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="intranet.sgbdd.saint-gobain.com" />
                </conditions>
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

I want any site, which is basically anything like `intranet.sgbdd.saint-gobain.com/start.asp?something_more`" to be forwarded / redirected to `intranet.stark-deutschland.net/start.asp?something_more`

For instance:

```
intranet.sgbdd.saint-gobain.com/start.asp?something_more --> intranet.stark-deutschland.net/start.asp?something_more
somesite.intranet.saint-gobain.com/my/new/site --> somesite.intranet.stark-deutschland.net/my/new/site
```

I also added conditions as suggested:

[image]

Thanks for you input

Comment: When the file version is 6.2, you are using IIS 8, https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/help/224609/how-to-obtain-versions-of-internet-information-server-iis You simply hit Mistake 1 https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Comment: @LexLi nice article. I went through it, but I can't seem to find my error here. I assume it has something to do with the Pattern, but even if I change it to `intranet.old-site.com` (without wildcards / regex) it doesn't work.

Comment: You didn't use a condition to check host name. That is the most typical mistake.

Comment: So i added 2 conditions as well, but still without luck: the 1st one being Input: `{HTTP_HOST}` matches pattern `(.*)intranet.old-site(.*)`, the 2nd one exactly the same, but with the full adress. Also changed "logical grouping" to `Match any`

Comment: Keep in mind no one else can see your screen, so edit your question to include the new information in whole, not partially. Also learn how to troubleshoot on your own, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules then the cause should be clear.

Comment: As suggested, I updated the question and read the doc you linked, but I'm still not able to solve it, I'm sorry, but I'd appreciate any pointers in where I'm screwing this up.

Comment: "Pattern" under "Match URL" is still wrong. You might learn how to locate IIS configuration file, and then check the XML elements for rewrite rules. Once that's clear to you, go back to my blog post and see what I actually meant.

Comment: Okay, I have no clue or ideas anymore, I'm sorry. Mind helping me with the solution and pointing out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using two URL rewrite rules is much easier to handle this.
If you want to redirect

```
intranet.sgbdd.saint-gobain.com/start.asp?something_more --> intranet.stark-deutschland.net/start.asp?something_more
somesite.intranet.saint-gobain.com/my/new/site --> somesite.intranet.stark-deutschland.net/my/new/site
```

Then rule can be like this.

```
  <rule name="rule1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(.*)saint-gobain.com$" />
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="intranet.sgbdd.saint-gobain.com" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://{C:1}stark-deutschland.net/{R:1}" redirectType="Temporary" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="rule2" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^intranet.sgbdd.saint-gobain.com$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://intranet.stark-deutschland.net/{R:1}" redirectType="Temporary" />
            </rule>
```

[image]
[image]

I tried to combine two rules to one rule but there's something wrong with expression ?! so it is recommended to split into two rules.

If you means

```
intranet.sgbdd.saint-gobain.com/start.asp?something_more --> intranet.stark-deutschland.net/start.asp?something_more
somesite.intranet.sgbdd.saint-gobain.com/my/new/site --> somesite.intranet.stark-deutschland.net/my/new/site
```

Then the rule can be like this.

```
<rule name="RewriteSG2DE" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://{C:1}stark-deutschland.net/{R:1}" redirectType="Temporary" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="(.*)sgbdd.saint-gobain.com" />
                </conditions>
        </rule>
```

Comment: works perfect! I guess my mistake was the `match url` thing, where I had to specify `(.*)` instead of a certain path. Thank you!